# my Discord bot command prefix not working

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Im making a simple discord server bot in python and im tryan use "sudo" as my command prefix, for some strange reason when i try the prefix ex "sudo hi" or something like that it dosent work. When i try a preifx such as "/" it works. Could anyone explain why?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "sudo")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is online")
```

Comment: Can you try adding a space to the end of the command prefix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current prefix is "sudo", therefore a valid command would be, for example, "sudohi". As @chiragzq suggested, adding a space to your prefix definition should fix your issue.

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "sudo ")
```